# How to get eyesight hitpoint in a 2d uwp window In Hololens2?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, native, hololens

I am developing a 2d uwp program for hololense 2,I need to get the eyes hitpoint on the window,that is like I have 4 rectangles in the window and I need to firgure out which target I am watching by using eye-tracking provided by hololens 2.

This is easy to accomplish in Unity3d but I need to use eye-gaze in DirectX.

I can get the headset position & direction by the Eye-tracking API provided by Microsoft(the EyesPose class),but I failed to get the window's position,what is worse is that the window can be rotated and scaled up ,how can I get the 3d position of my window? or Can the window be tag-along like in the MRTK toolkit in Unity3d ?

Any answer is welcome.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [BoundingBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxcollision/nf-directxcollision-boundingbox-boundingbox(constxmfloat3__constxmfloat3_)) to each rectangle, and then call the [BoundingBox :: Intersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxcollision/nf-directxcollision-boundingbox-intersects(constboundingfrustum_)) method in each frame. This method will compute the intersection of the ray with a BoundingBox using the slabs method based on the Origin and Direction of the ray. This can help you figure out which target user is watching.

This sample provides a demonstration of using the API: [Spatial interaction source sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/SpatialInteractionSource/cpp/Content/Whiteboard.cpp#L51)